# How can I store, and read setting data to Preference?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to store `flick_level_number` to preference.
But this doesn't work :( How can I store it as `flick_level_number`?
and How can I read onCreate?

```
public void selectSensibility(int level_number){
    switch (level_number) {
    case 0:
         flick_width_sensibility = 0.2f;
         flick_height_sensibility = 0.3f;
         flick_level_number = 0;
         break;
    case 1:
         flick_width_sensibility = 0.4f;
         flick_height_sensibility = 0.2f;
         flick_level_number = 1;
         break;
    case 2:
         flick_width_sensibility = 0.6f;
         flick_height_sensibility = 0.15f;
         flick_level_number = 2;
         break;
    } 

   //Here, I want to store `flick_level_number` to Preference
    Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString(
      "flick_level_number", writeEditText.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();

}
```

**LogCat**

```
08-14 22:05:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(9413): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 22:05:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(9413): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 22:05:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(9413):     at com.sample.MainActivity.selectSensibility(MainActivity.java:240)
08-14 22:05:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(9413):     at com.sample.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:270)
08-14 22:05:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(9413):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:980)
08-14 22:05:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(9413):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
08-14 22:05:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(9413):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1150)
08-14 22:05:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(9413):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:4397)
08-14 22:05:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(9413):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2985)
08-14 22:05:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(9413):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3671)
08-14 22:05:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(9413):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-14 22:05:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(9413):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-14 22:05:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(9413):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
08-14 22:05:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(9413):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
08-14 22:05:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(9413):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 22:05:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(9413):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-14 22:05:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(9413):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
08-14 22:05:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(9413):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
08-14 22:05:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(9413):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: How did you determine that that didn't work?

Comment: check this tutorial http://androiddeveloperspot.blogspot.com/2013/01/sharedpreference-in-android.html

Comment: @Niek Because applications shuts down when it's fired

Comment: Then you should post a stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just say to the preference class you want to store a int:

```
 editor.putInt("name", put your int value here);
 instead of
 editor.putString();
```

You can still saving your flick_level_number as String, you just need to parse the  string to a int:

```
     myNum = Integer.parseInt(your preference that store your value);
```

And onCreate:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity); 
     // getpreferences
     SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Your preference file", 0);  
     final float  value= settings.getFloat("flick_level_number", your default value);
     final int value1 = settings.getInt("flick_level_number", your default value);
         final String value2 = settings.getIString("flick_level_number", "your default value");

}
```

Your nullpointer is: sharedPref to fix this

```
         sharedPref  = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile", 0);
    Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("flick_level_number", flick_level_number);
    editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks But it still shuts down:( with this code `editor.putInt("flick_level_number", flick_level_number);`

Comment: what do you mean by saying "my default value"?

Comment: "my default value" means the default value you want to set for the preference. Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753800/android-default-values-for-shared-preferences/17757046#17757046

Comment: ahh!! now I think I got it. So no data exists in preference, default value will be set to preference automatically by just coding one line. Right?

Comment: By the way why did it still shut down? I tried your code `editor.putInt("flick_level_number", flick_level_number);`

Comment: yes... my guess is you are not setting the file correctly...can you show your code for this object: sharedPref

Comment: sorry I don't have any code related to sharedPref except the 1st line to define `SharedPreferences sharedPref;`

Comment: can you post it please?

Comment: This code covers all. All I wanna do is loading previous setting referring Preference and set the value on launch. and save `flick_level_number` to Preference when it's selected

Comment: The issue is:  sharedPref is null. try add this code in on your onCreate Method :    sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("name your file", 0);... Also you can add this line of code above Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

Comment: Thanks:) and `final int value1 = settings.getInt("flick_level_number", your default value);` to load?

Comment: yes, just make sure each time you want to put or get a value from your preferences, your sharedPref object is not null :D...

Comment: Thanks for great answer. now I totally understood! by the way, is it accessible to pref without root? I wanna just see inside of the data if it's working there

Comment: nop in real device... if you run your app in a emulator you get root access, also you can print the values of your preferences and see the value on logcat... like: System.out.println(value); or Log.d("My activity name","my value");.... etc

Comment: for `settings.getInt()", it makes sense to let it have default value, but what about `getSharedPreferences`? You did set 0, but I thought that you only need the name for it since it's just like a filename to hold many keys. Why do we need default value for that?

Comment: is not default value is open mode: Operating mode. Use 0 or MODE_PRIVATE for the default operation, MODE_WORLD_READABLE and MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE to control permissions. The bit MODE_MULTI_PROCESS can also be used if multiple processes are mutating the same SharedPreferences file. MODE_MULTI_PROCESS is always on in apps targetting Gingerbread (Android 2.3) and below, and off by default in later versions.

Comment: Perfect Answer. Now everything makes sense. Thanks so much:)