# When saved a value in SharedPreferences I can't get the value that I store

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using `context.getSharedPreferences` to store a string and some boolean.

```kotlin
private const val PREFS_NAME = "com.example.domotique.DomoticzWidget"
private const val PREF_PREFIX_KEY = "appwidget_"
internal fun get_path(appWidgetId: Int, key:String): String{
    return PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId + key
}

internal fun get_pref(context: Context): SharedPreferences {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
}

internal fun saveWidgetPref(context: Context, appWidgetId: Int, key:String, value:Any) {
    val prefs = get_pref(context).edit()

    val path = get_path(appWidgetId, key)
    if (value is Boolean){
        prefs.putBoolean(path, value)
    }

    if (value is String){
        prefs.putString(path, value)
    }
    prefs.commit()
    Log.d("custom", "Valeurs sauvegardées pour $path: $value")

}
```

But When I'm using my function to get what I store previously I get the default value.

```kotlin
internal fun getWidgetPref(context: Context, appWidgetId: Int, key:String, type_value: Any): Any? {
    val prefs = get_pref(context)

    var value: Any? = null
    val path = get_path(appWidgetId, key)
    if (type_value is Boolean){
        value = prefs.getBoolean(path, false)
    }

    if (type_value is String){
        value = prefs.getString(path, "do")!!
    }
    Log.d("custom", "Valeurs trouvés pour $path: ${value}")
    return value
}
```

Here is my log with only the tag custom

```
2024-01-24 13:29:56.739 27234-27234 custom                  com.example.domotique                D  Value stored for appwidget_154Portail: false
2024-01-24 13:29:56.739 27234-27234 custom                  com.example.domotique                E  CheckBox Portail est cochée : false
2024-01-24 13:29:56.742 27234-27234 custom                  com.example.domotique                D  Value stored for appwidget_154Lumiere: false
2024-01-24 13:29:56.742 27234-27234 custom                  com.example.domotique                E  CheckBox Lumiere est cochée : false
2024-01-24 13:29:56.743 27234-27234 custom                  com.example.domotique                D  Value stored for appwidget_154widget_label: Do action
2024-01-24 13:29:56.744 27234-27234 custom                  com.example.domotique                D  Value found for appwidget_154widget_label: do
2024-01-24 13:29:56.745 27234-27234 custom                  com.example.domotique                E  widget_label : do
```

I don't know why I not getting the right value

Comment: Did you have read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753800/android-default-values-for-shared-preferences

Comment: @writer_chris yes, but the thing is that I now how works the default value. I already made an app with SharedPreferences and worked well on the same API version (33), but my problem now is that I'm always getting the default value and I don't know why.

Comment: first i would define sharedPrefs as a private val ... and please try prefs.getBoolean(path, false).commit() and prefs.getString(path, "do").commit() and remove pref.commit please try

Comment: thank you I solve my problem. It was a toString missing after `binding.widgetLabel.text` being an input area and so the variable itself not a string